# How to launch the normal function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some links to launch ajax.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="artClick(1)">1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="artClick(2)">2</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="artClick(3)">3</a><br>
.
.
```

These links are made by script so I cant use #id.

my javascript is this

```
function artClick(id){

  $.post(url,
  {
      id:id
  },function(data){
  });   
}
```

but it doesnt work.
I think I should use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

But if I put the function in this,nothing changes.

I want to know the good way to handle the multiple links and ajax.

Comment: `ready` not needed since jQuery code is wrapped in function that can't execute before page is loaded. There is nothing fundamentally wrong in code shown ( assuming url is valid). Inspect request in browser console network tab for clues

Comment: why do you think it doesn't work? how have you tested it?

Comment: WHAT doesn't work?  Your description doesn't tell us what isn't working and what you need help with.  Did you look in the browser console for script errors?  Have you put a `console.log()` statement or breakpoint in your `artClick()` function to verify that it's getting called?  Is the ajax call getting made?  Does the success handler for the ajax function get called?

Comment: Where are your URLs? change href="javascript:void(0)" with your actual URL and send this object in your scripting method then get url and id from this.

Comment: Iis just my mistake I omit ',' in one sentence,and javascript error....thanks alot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 : include [jQuery library](http://jquery.com) in

2 : add ready(); function

3 : inside ready function add such

```
$("a").click(function(){
   atext = $(this).text();
   $.post(url,{id:atext},function(data){
    // here what do you want
   });
});
```